# Spring Jackson Serialization infinite recursion

Tags: spring, serialization, jackson

I have a Spring REST service whose API controller returns an object `A`. I am getting the following exception:

```
Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.company.product.platform.service.contract.A[\"b\"]->com.company.product.data.B[\"c\"]);
```

Here are the object definitions

```
public class A {
  private final B b;
  private final DateTime time;
  private final String s;
  private final long l;
}
```

Classes `B`, `C`, and `D` are part of a third party library.

```
public class B{
  private final C c;
}

public class C implements Iterable<D>{
  private final Map<String, D> props;
}
```

I don't quite understand why I am hitting an infinite loop. Would greatly appreciate an explanation/solution.

**UPDATE**

I got the serialization to work by making some modifications. Here is the explanation of what I did:

The only reason I have `B` as a member of `A` is so that I can get access the props map that is a member of `C`. So, I created a copy of the props map and made it a member of `A`. `A` now looks like:

```
public class A {
      private final Map<String, D> props;
      private final DateTime time;
      private final String s;
      private final long l;
    }
```

This works fine. I feel like this narrows down the issue to B or C. C seems more interesting as it implements `Iterable`. Is there a problem with serializing a class that implements `Iterable`?

Comment: Show us the code of class `C`